# is_wp_error() and handling errors

Tags: errors, transient, customization

Im trying to build a function which grabs the feedburner "readers" using `wp_remote_get()`. I noticed that it frequently returned a value of `0`.

I assumed at first that it was a WordPress error (handled by `is_wp_error()`) or a flaw with `wp_remote_get()`. Wrong of-course..

Feedburner just kept crashing, so I used a second transient to store a result (never `0`) with an expiration of 7 days. The part which i cant get my head around is handling errors with `is_wp_error()`. I need to force an error so i can handle it properly, before I put it up on production.

Heres an illustration:

```
$result = wp_remote_get( 'http://feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=' . urlencode($username) );

if ( is_wp_error($result) )
    return false;
```

Whats the best way to force an error? Should i use `new WP_error()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WordPress can be inconsistent as to when is returns a `WP_Error` object and when it just returns `false` or `string(0)` when actually there was an error. I am not sure exactly what feedburner is returning that is not triggering a `WP_Error` from `wp_remote_get()` - but if you know `wp_remote_get()` will return an WP_Error, I would just set `$result = new WP_Error( 'my-error' );` This is the same object that `wp_remote_get()` will return on error.

Comment: I haven't encountered an instance where `wp_remote_get()` triggers a `wp_error` so im not sure if that's the case. But i wanted to create some sort of fallback in case it does. Ill use your suggestions and see what it gives me. Thanks Joe.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you again. It worked great. Thanks for looking out +1

Answer (score -1):

To grab Feedburner stats, I've always used `wp_cache_get`. Here's a function I've had success with

```
function get_feedburner_stats() {
  $fbrefreshtime = 43200;  //Refresh Feedburner twice in a day

  $fb = wp_cache_get('fbstats_key');

  if ($fb == false) {
    $yourfeeduri = 'YOUR_FEEDBURNER_USERID'; 
    $feed = 'https://feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri='.$yourfeeduri;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $feed);
    $feed = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($feed);
    $fb = $xml->feed->entry['circulation']; 

    //Set the Value in Cache
    wp_cache_set('fbstats_key', strval($fb), '', $fbrefreshtime);
  }
  return $fb;
}
```

To return the value, I use this

```
<?php echo get_feedburner_stats(); ?>
```

That being said, Feedburner is horribly unreliable. What I'd recommend doing is building in a conditional that if the number = 0, then it returns a static number.

Comment: great suggestion, but I'm looking to trigger a `wp_error`, not recreate the entire function using cURL let alone use `wp_cache_get()`. The WordPress codex even suggests staying away from them and use the [Transients API instead](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache#Role_of_the_WordPress_Object_Cache)

Comment: +1 @VicePrez. @Norcross, nice suggestion, but stick to standards and use the available API/wrappers, namely the already mentioned Transients as well as HTTP - http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API